# how to add boost documentation to qt creator

Tags: c++, boost, autocomplete, qt-creator

I am currently starting to use the boost library in qt creator(2.3.0), but the autocomplete feature doensn't work properly. I am wondering if anyone knows what tweaks I need to do in order to acces the autocomplete feature.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::regex re;
    std::string haystack = "This is a needle in a haystack";
    std::string needle = "a*";
    re.assign(needle, boost::regex_constants::icase);
    if(boost::regex_match(haystack, re))
        std::cout << "Match" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Not match" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code works flawlessly(output is "Not match" as expected), however autocomplete seems to be off. For example, if I type bo, then ctrl+space, I get no suggestion.

Thank you in advance, 
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autocompletion does work with Qt Creator. In fact QtCreator can autocomplete boost code where some other IDE fails.
Somethimes though the code completion tend to bug, try to reload your project and you should be fine. And of course, like most of the IDEs, no project means no code completion.

Comment: Reloaded the project and now it works well. I wonder why I didn't thought about that :/.

Comment: By mention "reload" you mean close and open it again? I have the same case with boost filesystem, the only auto-completion I have is `#include"boost/filesystem.hpp"` :(